# File management for iOS

Tags: macos, ios, applications

What are some better solutions (apps or any ways) to manage files (folders and subfolders with PDFs, docs, video, audio etc.) on iOS device (iPhone or iPad) that can sync with OS X?

Currently I'm using "USB Disk Pro" but I have to manually create the folders in iTunes and drag and drop each files manually. (Image if there are 10 folders with 50 files in each folders to be transfer from OS X to iPad.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) would be a good solution.

1. The Dropbox app will automatically create a folder on your OS X. Put files that you want to access on your iOS devices into the folder.
2. Install the iOS app on your iOS devices. You will be able to access all the files that's stored in the OS X folder easily.

Note that there's a space limit for the Dropbox service.

Comment: the problem with DropBox I found is on the mobile device you have to click each files so to be downloaded onto the iOS device for offline use. USB Disk Pro allow full office use right after sync

Answer (score 0):

I use GoodReader with SCP to my local Mac. I now have a directory tree recursively mirrored between iPad and OS X, and any changes made to either will be reflected on the other after a sync. Conflicts are handled manually.

If you don't want to set up SCP/SSH, you can use DropBox too, it is just slower than a direct connection to your Mac on the local network.

In truth, I use a combination, mirroring some folders (~5 GB worth) via SCP, and a few others via DropBox, just in separate trees on the Mac and on the iPad.